# Iterating over ArrayEntity

Tags: twig, shopware6

We were have this backend code:

```
$event->getPage()->addExtension('downloads', new ArrayEntity($downloads));
```

In the twig

```
{{ dump(page.extensions.downloads) }}
```

shows the Array entity.

Before the Shopware updates

This loop worked:

```
{% for key, files in page.extensions.downloads.data %}
```

But now it doesn't (data is null)

Also

```
{% for key, files in page.extensions.downloads %}
```

does not work.

How to iterate over the array entity in twig?

Comment: Any errors when you tried `for key, files in page.extensions.downloads`? It seems this should work as `ArrayEntity` implements `ArrayAcces`- [source](https://github.com/shopware/core/blob/trunk/Framework/Struct/ArrayEntity.php)

Comment: No errors, just not going into the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% for key, files in page.extensions.downloads.all %}
```

works